# Enable syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-review

**Please upvote this question and with enough votes, code syntax highlighting will be enabled on the site.**

---

I know other stack exchanges (and stack overflow) have syntax highlighting. Is that not available due to beta or a setting that needs to be enabled?

I have tried doing triple backticks followed by the language name (which I know works in other exchanges) but it does not render highlights.

Example: [What's the difference between Anchor Accounts and account attributes?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/587/whats-the-difference-between-anchor-accounts-and-account-attributes)

I had a quick google around and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) is the only remotely relevant thing I found.

Comment: I am pretty sure beta restrictions are a thing throughout the entire Stack Exchange galaxy

Comment: per https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta "*All beta sites have the same temporary placeholder design*"

Comment: It's by default turned off, but by posting on this meta, receiving enough upvotes, and having a mod add the [status-review] tag, it can be enabled: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296833/282094 - it's correct to use your backticks and specify a language, once it's enabled, if it ever is, then the post won't need to be edited again.

Comment: @Rob's link leads to two good examples of how to use a Meta forum to make feature requests: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104189/230261), and [here](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/enable-youtube-embeds-for-woodworking).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to illicit votes. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: @sohrab "elicit" - evoke, draw out; "illicit" - naughty ;^)

Comment: I forgot to ask: how many naughty votes are enough votes to get this thing turned on?